# Why don't work find method and how get data in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, routes

This is my code:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(params.get('id')); // THIS IS WORKS
      this.currentOrganization = this.getOrganizationId(params.get('id'));
      console.log(this.currentOrganization); // THIS IS UNDEFINED
    } );  
  }

  getOrganizationId(id: string) {
    let organizations = this.orgService.getOrganizations(); // THIS IS WORKS
    return organizations.find(p => p.id == id);
  }
```

Why undefined this.currentOrganization? How do I get the organization's information for params.get('id')?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular)

Comment: Does the `return organizations.find(blah)` actually return the id or is it undefined?

Comment: Maybe you can console.log `organizations.find(p => p.id == id)` first and see if it actually returns any value.

Comment: u have async problem. u need to subscribe it and take it inside subscribe

Answer (score 0):

You can try add `if(organizations)` before the running the `.find` so it will only start to `.find` once there're values in `organizations`. Like so

```
getOrganizationId(id: string) {
    let organizations = this.orgService.getOrganizations();
    if(organizations) {
        console.log(organizations.find(p => p.id == id));
        return organizations.find(p => p.id == id);
    }
}
```

If you want to try a different approach, you may want to try this one

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getOrganization();
}

getOrganization() {
    const organizationId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    if (organizationId) {
      this.orgService.getOrganizations()
         .subscribe(org => {
                      console.log(org.find(p => p.id == organizationId));
                      return org.find(p => p.id == organizationId);
                    });
}
```

Though for me it's best to have a specific service that just returns the get with `id` as we do still take it from the route. It will be faster loading instead of having to go through it again once the data list has been fetch.